# Ansible: move on to the next task if the task is completed on one host

Tags: ansible

In ansible what i require is to check for a file is available on two hosts. But if the file is available on even one host i need to cancel the task on other host and move onto the next task. The reason why i require this is because a the next task can only be done if that particular file is available and that file can be randomly written to any of the hosts.

Comment: stat module can be used to check the stats

Answer (score 2):

The following play does exactly what you want:

```
---
- hosts:
    - server1
    - server2
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    file_name: 'foo.bar'

  tasks:
  - name: wait for file
    wait_for:
      path: '{{ file_name }}'
      state: present
      timeout: 30
    ignore_errors: True

  - name: stat
    stat:
      path: '{{ file_name }}'
    register: result

  - name: next
    debug:
      msg: "File {{ file_name }} available on {{ ansible_host }}"
    when: result.stat.isreg is defined and result.stat.isreg
```

The output is:

```
PLAY [server1,server2] *********************************************************

TASK [wait for file] ***********************************************************
ok: [server1]
fatal: [server2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 3, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for file foo.bar"}
...ignoring

TASK [stat] ********************************************************************
ok: [server1]
ok: [server2]

TASK [next] ********************************************************************
skipping: [server2]
ok: [server1] => {
    "msg": "File foo.bar available on server1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server1                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
server2                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. but when i tried the debug task fails on one server. moreover what i require is to halt the playbook on file checking task until the file is available on one of the server. the requirement for this is another parallel task which is also running with my playbook i can continue the rest of the tasks when that other task is finished only. when that task is finished it will write a file to one of the servers randomly. i tried doing this with wait_for module and stat module with polling both not functioning as the way i require to.

Comment: Enhanced answer

Comment: thanks again. But still this will wait on server2 for 30 even if the file is found on the server1. as i mentioned what i need is immediately move to the next task if the file is found on one server.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stat module to check the status like below and for also you can add the serial:1 below hosts:  in your playbook

- stat:
  path: /path/to/something
  register: p
- debug:
  msg: "Path exists and is a directory"
  when: p.stat.isdir is defined and p.stat.isdir

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html for more details